# Android: How to add custom fonts to theme/style/xml

Tags: android, fonts

I know how to set the custom font to a TextView. But how to add custom font through theme/style/xml ??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="customfontforlistview" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">HOW_TO_CUSTOM_FONT</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Please provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there isn't a good way to do this. The best alternative that I know is to create a simple subclass that looks something like this:

```
public class CustomTextViewNormal extends TextView
{
    public CustomTextViewNormal(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextViewNormal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextViewNormal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

If you make this, you can just use this custom text view in the xml layouts and you basically have the same functionality as a style although, admittedly, a bit sloppier.

Comment: this is not a downvote! right answer. at least one way how to do it

Comment: android:textStyle="bold" is not working on this inherited textview :(